# Running a for loop iteration on Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an model $club which is related to another model $events.

I query the database for clubs using this

```
$clubs = Club::get()->where('city', $city);
```

Then for the events, I am trying to copy all the events associated to ALL clubs by doing

```
foreach ($clubs as $club) 
                {

                $events = Event::where('club_id', $club->id)->get()->sortBy('date');

                }
```

The problem is when I echo events, I only see the events for just one club rather than all the clubs, its almost like my loop isn't iterating.

Comment: Please read about relation in laravel

Comment: Query like this:  `Club::where('city', $city)->get();` otherwise you will fetch all cities in the query.

Comment: @NikleshRaut I have tried to and I am asking for help due to my lack of experience/understanding.

Comment: @Daan Can you please explain what you mean? I am getting all the cities okay, its just getting all the events tied to a club that I am struggling with.

Comment: Yes it works, but performance wise it will be better. In your example the raw query will be: `SELECT * FROM clubs` in my example it will be `SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE city = :city`.

Comment: @Daan Thanks very much for your help Fully understand you now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best pratices and performance, use the Laravel relationships.

In your Club Model includes [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) function like this:

```php
public function events()
{
   return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Event::class);
}
```

Then your controller..

```php
$clubs = Club::where('city', $city)
  ->with(['events' => function($query) {
     $query->sortBy('date');
  }])
  ->get();
```

After this, you will have events in your Collect $clubs

If you want only the events, could get by this

```php
$events = $clubs->pluck('events');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by doing this. You don't need a loop.

```
$clubs = Club::where('city', $city)->get();
$club_ids = $clubs->pluck("id")->toArray();
$events = Event::wherein('club_id',$club_ids)->sortBy('date')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked like a charm but I then ran into another problem. I intend to sort the events out by date, but the issue is they're stored in the format dd/mm/yy and at the minute it's just using the day to sort it out. I know I neeed to use the strtotime function to convert my date and then sort that, can I embed functions within eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

@Mehran gave the best answer, but just to fix your problem check it:

If you are printing `$events` after the loop, you are overwriting the `$events` variable and you just see the last value of the iteration.

Transforming `$events` in `array` and assinging values in differente keys, after the loop you will see all events.

```
$events = [];
foreach ($clubs as $club) {
    $events[] = Event::where('club_id', $club->id)->get()->sortBy('date');
}
dd($events);
```